# LeetCode 768: Constructing a variation on a solution for Max Chunks To Make Sorted

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

LeetCode's [Max Chunks To Make Sorted II](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-chunks-to-make-sorted-ii/) challenge is:

> Given an array `arr` of integers (not necessarily distinct), we split
> the array into some number of "chunks" (partitions), and individually
> sort each chunk.  After concatenating them, the result equals the
> sorted array.
>
> What is the most number of chunks we could have made?

Example:

```
Input: arr = [2, 1, 3, 4, 4]
Output: 4
Explanation:
We can split into two chunks, such as [2, 1], [3, 4, 4].
However, splitting into [2, 1], [3], [4], [4] is the highest number of chunks possible.
```

The [algorithm underlying the following solution is](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-chunks-to-make-sorted-ii/solution/) (the algorithm and the solution were posted as a comment on the solution page by a user named @benevolent. Unfortunately, I can't link to its comment):

> If the largest number from `arr[0]` to (including) `arr[k]` is less than or equal to the smallest
> number from `arr[k+1]` to the end, then we can split into two valid
> chunks.
> To illustrate:
>
> ```
>    left        right  
> [......max] [min......]
> ```
>
> To know the minimum element from `k` to `arr.length-1`, we can just
> precompute from right to left.

The solution:

```js
function maxChunksToSorted(arr) {
  var minRight = Array(arr.length).fill(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
  for (var i = arr.length-2; i >= 0; --i) {
    minRight[i] = Math.min(minRight[i+1], arr[i+1]);
  }
  var maxLeft = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
  var ans = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    maxLeft = Math.max(maxLeft, arr[i]);
    if (maxLeft <= minRight[i]) {
      ans += 1
    }
  }
  return ans;
};
console.log("expects: 1", "got:", maxChunksToSorted([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log("expects: 4", "got:", maxChunksToSorted([2, 1, 3, 4, 4]));
```

**My question:**

I was trying to make a "mirror image" of the above solution, by "flipping" every action (e.g, the use of `min` becomes `max`, `<=` becomes `>`, and so on).

My `maxArr` indeed mirrors `minRight` (e.g., for `[2, 1, 3, 4, 4]`, my `maxArr` is `[MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, 1, 3, 4, 4]`, while the original `minRight` is `[1, 3, 4, 4, MAX_SAFE_INTEGER]`), but it clearly doesn't work, and I can't put my finger on the reason for that.

What's my fundamental problem?

Let me stress that I'm not looking for some other working solution. I'd like to understand what went wrong with my mirror solution, if it's even possible to make this mirror, and if not - what's the fundamental reason for that.

```js
function maxChunksToSorted(arr) {
  var maxArr = Array(arr.length).fill(Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);
  for (var i = 1; i <= arr.length; ++i) {
    maxArr[i] = Math.max(maxArr[i-1], arr[i]);
  }
  var minLeft = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  var ans = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    minLeft = Math.min(minLeft, arr[i]);
    if (minLeft > maxArr[i]) {
      ans += 1
    }
  }
  return ans;
};
console.log("expects: 1", "got:", maxChunksToSorted([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log("expects: 4", "got:", maxChunksToSorted([2, 1, 3, 4, 4]));
```

Comment: I haven't really understood the code... but I see 2 differences:
1. The original solution has `minRight[i] = Math.max(minRight[i+1], arr[i+1]);` whereas yours has `maxArr[i] = Math.max(maxArr[i-1], arr[i]);`. Notice the missing `-1`. 2: Pretty sure your `for (var i = 1; i <= arr.length; ++i)` should be `< arr.length`, not `<= arr.length`.

Comment: A chunk ends when the beginning and the ending of it are inside of it. If this isn't enough for you to figure out a solution, tell me and I write an elaborated answer.

Comment: What is `currrentMax` in the context? would it be the maximum value of the current chunk? If it is, should it be initially set to a very small value and then, be set as `currentMax = Math.max(currentMax, arr[i])`, so it really stores the maximum value?

Comment: Also, I think this doesn't work because you seem to be only paying attention to the MAXIMUM value of a chunk, but the chunk also needs to have the MINIMUM value inside of it. If the minimum value of it isn't inside of it yet and you found the maximum value, you cannot end the chunk immediatly.

Comment: Your'e right, the naming of `currentMax` is wrong. It should be `minLeft`, to mirror the original `maxLeft`, so I'll edit it in. `maxLeft` is indeed the maximum value of the current chunk, while `minLeft` is the minimum value of the current chunk. If it still doesn't make sense to you, I encourage you to raise your doubts, because it would probably help me understand what's wrong with my mirroring.

Comment: Oh, I now see what should be done. As the illustration shows, a chunk must end in the maximum value, and the next chunk must start with the minimum value. The original solution constructs an array of minimum values, thus preparing each chunk starting point (that's the illustration's `right`). The second loop then creates each chunk's ending point (that's the illustration's `left`), thus setting the boundary between two adjacent chunks. My solution starts by first constructing each chunk's ending point, and thus its second loop should set each chunk's starting point. Still not sure how, though.

Comment: This sounds wrong. The chunk doesn't need to end in the maximum value. For example, [2,1,3,4,4]. The first chunk is [2,1]. As I said, the chunk ends when it contains the values that corresponds to the beginning and ending indexes of itself in the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
function chunk(list){
    let sortedList = list.slice();
    sortedList.sort();
    
    var beginIndex = -1; var biggestFound;
    var foundFirst = false; var foundLast = false; 
    
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if(beginIndex == -1) {
            if(list[i] == sortedList[i]) print(list[i]);
            else {beginIndex = i; biggestFound = list[i];}
        }
        else{
            if(list[i] == sortedList[beginIndex]) foundFirst = true;
            if(list[i] > biggestFound) biggestFound = list[i];
            if(biggestFound == sortedList[i]) foundLast = true;
            if(foundFirst && foundLast){
                print(list.slice(beginIndex, i - beginIndex + 1));                
                foundFirst = false; foundLast = false; beginIndex = -1;
            }           
        }
    }
}

chunk([2,1,3,4,4]);
```

As I commented, if a chunk starts at position `i`, it must contain the element that corresponds to the position `i` in the sorted array and if it ends in position `j`, it must contain the element in the index `j` of the sorted array.

When both of these conditions are satisfied, you close the chunk and start a new one.

The complexity is `O(n lg(n))`, where `n` is the size of the array.

Comment: I appreciate your effort! However, as stressed in my question, I'm not looking for another working solution. I'd like to understand what went wrong with my mirror solution, if it's even possible to make this mirror, and if not - what's the fundamental reason for that.